# tcolorbox minted library with python3 non-determinism

Tags: minted, latexmk, python, tcolorbox

Later versions of the package [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) allows formatting source code with its `minted` library (which uses the [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package).

When a document is compiled, a temporary file with extension `.pyg` is generated with LaTeX code created by the [`pygmentize`](http://pygments.org/) Python application.

I have noticed that with Python3 this generated file may differ from run to run, with its lines sorted differently each time. The lines are the same at each run, but not necessarily in the same order.

This is making [`latexmk`](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) run indefinitely when compiling a document. That happens because `latexmk` determines if a new run of the latex compiler is needed based on a checksum of the input files.

This bad behaviour is not seen with Python2.

Here is a minimal working example `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing engine=minted, minted language=java}
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Compilation command:

```
latexmk -pvc -pdf -latexoption=-shell-escape test
```

`latexmk` has in its output message:

```
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'test.pyg'
Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files
```

I am looking for a fix for `tcolorbox` using Python3.

Comment: I'd say that one must exclude `.pyg` files from the checks made by `latexmk`; they are used for the current run, not for the next one, so the fact that they heve changed is irrelevant.

Comment: I think you want to look at `%hash_calc_ignore_pattern` in the [`latexmk` docs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/). I expect that a rule something like `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pyg'} = '.*';` should work. As far as I can tell, there isn't a way just to ignore files with a particular extension, which would be more efficient.

Comment: @G.Poore Your suggestion of adding a rule to make `latexmk` ignore all lines of all files with the `.pyg` extension works for me. Maybe you want to add this as an answer. But this is an workaround. The generation of the file should be deterministic, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to look at `%hash_calc_ignore_pattern` in the [`latexmk docs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/). I expect that a rule something like `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pyg'} = '.*'`; should work. As far as I can tell, there isn't a way just to ignore files with a particular extension, which would be more efficient.

The `.pyg` file is a temp file generated by `minted`. It is meant to be deleted automatically by `minted` at the end of a compile. It *is* deleted when I replace the `tcblisting` environment with `minted` in the example.  But it *isn't* deleted when the `tcblisting` environment is used.  This is due to the interaction of a bug in `minted` with  the `tcolorbox` source.  Basically, the temp file isn't deleted due to the way that `tcolorbox` invokes `minted`. (The `\usemintedstyle` command neglects to delete its temp file.) This `minted` bug has been fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/gpoore/minted), which uses a more efficient scheme for deleting temp files. Just having the `minted` bug fixed might resolve you problems, without the need for the `latexmk` rule, since all `.pyg` files will be deleted.

The `.pyg` file is usually used multiple times per compile, but I think only once in the example (due to the workings of `tcolorbox`).  So if the document hasn't changed, then its contents shouldn't, even at intermediate steps. I'm not sure what Python 3 could be doing differently. Perhaps something in Pygments, though that seems very unlikely.